# How many items can I load in the code editor in a subfolder?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I use Google earth engine Python API to load images in an Asset folder.
When i tried to add a new subfolder in the code editor I get the error that it already exist even though I am not able to see it. The folder contains 1246 items (images and subfolders).

Now I looked into my code editor folder and I don't see it. After some check using the CLI I think there is a limit to the numbe rof asset that can be displayed at once. Can someone confirm ?

[image]

Comment: I've noticed a similar thing. A folder can contain many many assets but will not display all of them in the code editor. Unsure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the network traffic when you open an asset folder in the Code Editor, you'll see a GET request to the `listAssets` endpoint that looks something like:

[image: GET request details]

You'll see the same request if you run [`ee.data.listAssets`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-listassets) with the default `params`. Based on that, the Code Editor probably* shows a max of 1000 assets in a given folder, since that's the default `pageSize`.

---

*Earth Engine will return a `nextPageToken` in the response if the number of assets is larger than the `pageSize`, so it's possible the Code Editor would use that to make another request for the rest of the assets, but I didn't have a folder with > 1000 assets to test with.